# Get multple related objects from Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have such model in Django:

```
from django.db import models


class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SharedDocument(models.Model):
    workspace = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to get list of templates by workspace in SharedDocument.

I was doing this query:

```
>>> shared_documents = SharedDocument.objects.filter(workspace='1').prefetch_related('document')
>>> [shared_document.document.template_set.get() for shared_document in shared_documents]
```

But from my prospective it looks a little bit ugly. So the question is: "Is it possible to do what I want by forming query without this part: `[shared_document.document.template_set.get() for shared_document in shared_documents]`"?

To clarify: **As a result I want to have a list/QuerySet with Template objects.**

Regards,
Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my colleague Dmirty Yakutkin which don't have an account on stackoverflow:

The answer is:

```
Template.objects.filter(document__shareddocument__workspace="1")
```